# Labeling variables

Tags: labeling

I want to define a function that outputs, say, an arbitrary number of complex coordinates on a Riemann sphere, $z_i$.

In Mathematica, I have been using Subscript[z,i] to label the individual coordinates, but there seems to be issues with the Subscript function - for example, Subscript[z,i]Subscript[k,j] - Subscript[z,i]Subscript[k,j] does not seem to always evaluate to zero as it should.

So my question is, what is the best way of labeling variables?

I don't want to use zi, because its not as nice to read. Is there any reason I couldn't use z[i], for example? Is there a standard way to do it?

Here is an example of a function I have defined:

```
PTFactor[m_] := Product[(Subscript[z, i]-Subscript[z, i+1]),{i,1,m-1}]*(Subscript[z, m]-Subscript[z, 1]);
```

Where m is any integer.

Comment: I think using `z[i]` instead of `Subscript` might be a good idea in the long term (not as nice to read, but much better to manipulate). But I wonder if you are really correct with your statement that the given example would "somtimes" not evaluate to zero. I think it should and would consider it a bug if it wouldn't. Can you give an example when this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do, `z[i]`, which defines your sequence as a function with integer domain), can work fine. For example:

```
pt[m_] := Product[(z[i] - z[i + 1]), {i, 1, m - 1}]*(z[m] - z[1]);
```

For instance, `pt[2]` is

```
(z[1] - z[2]) (-z[1] + z[2])
```